# How to reference column name in Microsoft SSMS / T-SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have been using basic t-sql as part of  job for some time but have never really invested much time into developing my skillset and would class myself as beginner-moderate. I have a task whereby I have data for particular sporting competitions along with numerical data for each month e.g

```
Competition, StartDate, EndDate, Aug_2017_Total, September_2017_Total,October_2017_Total

English Premier Leage, 2017-08-01,2018-07-01, 20, 30, 45
```

And I need to basically create a total column which, if the column header for the numerical data e.g. Aug_2017_Total is between the start and end date, sums the contents e.g. Aug_2017_Total + September_2017_Total etc.

Pseudocode wise something like

```
sum(if columnanme like Total and columname between start date and end date)
```

however for the life of me I cannot find a way to reference column headers in this way. I have briefly looked into `col_name` and `sysobjects` but they do not seem to give me the functionality I am looking for...

I think I am missing something obvious...

Comment: I'd create a secondary table holding the information of months. I.e. `monthname`, `StartDate`, `EndDate`. i.e. `Aug_2017`, `01-08-2017`, `31-08-2017`. You can then use a `JOIN` to that table using the column to perform the join on , and determining the time period that way.

Comment: What you have missed is "normalization" of your data. Don't store data in a manner where a date is embedded into a column name. You need to "unpivot" that data structure. Is the table you display a permanent table of a temporary table? How often are you adding columns to that table? Also what does the StartDate and EndDate mean in that row you display? (start of what? end of what?)

Comment: Thanks All, much appreciated on your fast responses. Unfortunately i have no control over the structure of the table at this time, which is loaded from an excel file created by another aspect of the business into a permanent table. Additional columns will be added infrequently. Each row represents a competition and its run time so the start and end dates would be the start and end of the competition season (e.g. they run for roughly a year at a time)

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following will help demonstrate why you need to alter the way you store that data. Below I have used 3 queries all unioned together to produce a more normalized structure. Using such an approach you can add next month's data without needing to add a column, and it becomes way easier to sum data as well.

There are many assumptions about your data in what you see below, it is meant only as a guide.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/31de24/5)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([Competition] varchar(21), [StartDate] date, [EndDate] date, [Aug_2017_Total] int, [September_2017_Total] int, [October_2017_Total] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([Competition], [StartDate], [EndDate], [Aug_2017_Total], [September_2017_Total], [October_2017_Total])
VALUES
    ('English Premier Leage', '2017-08-01', '2017-07-01', 20, 30, 45),
    ('English Premier Leage', '2017-09-01', '2017-09-01', 20, 30, 45),
    ('English Premier Leage', '2017-10-01', '2017-10-01', 20, 30, 45)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
   Competition
   , startdate
   , concat(datename(month,startdate) + '_', year(startdate) ) MonthLabel
   , MonthValue
from (
    select Competition, StartDate, Aug_2017_Total as MonthValue
    from table1
    where StartDate = '20170801'
    UNION ALL
    select Competition, StartDate, September_2017_Total as MonthValue
    from table1
    where StartDate = '20170901'
    UNION ALL
    select Competition, StartDate, October_2017_Total as MonthValue
    from table1
    where StartDate = '20171001'
    ) unpiv
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/31de24/5/0)**:

```
|           Competition |  startdate |     MonthLabel | MonthValue |
|-----------------------|------------|----------------|------------|
| English Premier Leage | 2017-08-01 |    August_2017 |         20 |
| English Premier Leage | 2017-09-01 | September_2017 |         30 |
| English Premier Leage | 2017-10-01 |   October_2017 |         45 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select 
     Competition
   , SUM(MonthValue)
from (
    select Competition, StartDate, Aug_2017_Total as MonthValue
    from table1
    where StartDate = '20170801'
    UNION ALL
    select Competition, StartDate, September_2017_Total as MonthValue
    from table1
    where StartDate = '20170901'
    UNION ALL
    select Competition, StartDate, October_2017_Total as MonthValue
    from table1
    where StartDate = '20171001'
    ) unpiv
where startdate >= '20170801' 
and startdate < '20180801'
group by
     Competition
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/31de24/5/1)**:

```
|           Competition |    |
|-----------------------|----|
| English Premier Leage | 95 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to consider *UNPIVOT*.  It can give you one place to add new columns instead of writing an entire select statement each time there's a change.

The *_Months* CTE is used to match which month a total column should be matched to.  If you were to stick with the naming convention *{MMM[M]}_{yyyy}_Total* then this should continue to work for you.

The *_Results* CTE is there for you to query further to get the output you're interested in.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/323fd/2/0)

**Set Up Test Data:**

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('dbo.Scores') IS NOT NULL) DROP TABLE dbo.Scores; 
GO 

CREATE TABLE dbo.Scores (
    Competition varchar(50), 
    StartDate date, 
    EndDate date, 
    Aug_2017_Total int, 
    September_2017_Total int, 
    October_2017_Total int
); 

INSERT Scores 
    (Competition, StartDate, EndDate, Aug_2017_Total, September_2017_Total, October_2017_Total)
VALUES
    ('English Premier League', '2017-08-01', '2017-08-31', 20, 30, 45),
    ('English Premier League', '2017-09-01', '2017-09-30', 20, 30, 45),
    ('English Premier League', '2017-10-01', '2017-10-30', 20, 30, 45),
    ('Serie A', '2017-08-01', '2017-08-31', 20, 30, 45),
    ('Serie A', '2017-09-01', '2017-09-30', 20, 30, 45),
    ('Serie A', '2017-10-01', '2017-10-30', 20, 30, 45),
    ('La Liga', '2017-08-01', '2017-08-31', 20, 30, 45),
    ('La Liga', '2017-09-01', '2017-09-30', 20, 30, 45),
    ('La Liga', '2017-10-01', '2017-10-30', 20, 30, 45),
    ('Bundesliga', '2017-08-01', '2017-08-31', 20, 30, 45),
    ('Bundesliga', '2017-09-01', '2017-09-30', 20, 30, 45),
    ('Bundesliga', '2017-10-01', '2017-10-30', 20, 30, 45),
    ('Major League Soccer', '2017-08-01', '2017-08-31', 20, 30, 45),
    ('Major League Soccer', '2017-09-01', '2017-09-30', 20, 30, 45),
    ('Major League Soccer', '2017-10-01', '2017-10-30', 20, 30, 45); 
GO
```

**Query**

```
WITH _Months AS (
    SELECT 1 [MonthNumber], 'January' [MonthFullName] 
    UNION ALL SELECT 2 [MonthNumber], 'February' [MonthFullName] 
    UNION ALL SELECT 3 [MonthNumber], 'March' [MonthFullName] 
    UNION ALL SELECT 4 [MonthNumber], 'April' [MonthFullName] 
    UNION ALL SELECT 5 [MonthNumber], 'May' [MonthFullName] 
    UNION ALL SELECT 6 [MonthNumber], 'June' [MonthFullName] 
    UNION ALL SELECT 7 [MonthNumber], 'July' [MonthFullName] 
    UNION ALL SELECT 8 [MonthNumber], 'August' [MonthFullName] 
    UNION ALL SELECT 9 [MonthNumber], 'September' [MonthFullName] 
    UNION ALL SELECT 10 [MonthNumber], 'October' [MonthFullName] 
    UNION ALL SELECT 11 [MonthNumber], 'November' [MonthFullName] 
    UNION ALL SELECT 12 [MonthNumber], 'December' [MonthFullName] 
), 
_Results AS (
  SELECT 
    Competition, 
    StartDate, 
    EndDate, 
    X.Points -- ... Points FOR ...
    -- X.ColumnName, -- ... FOR ColumnName IN ...
  FROM 
    Scores S 
    UNPIVOT(
        Points FOR ColumnName IN (
            Aug_2017_Total, 
            September_2017_Total, 
            October_2017_Total
            -- add new columns here as the table structure changes
        )
    ) X 
    INNER JOIN _Months M ON M.MonthFullName LIKE LEFT(X.ColumnName, CHARINDEX('_', X.ColumnName) - 1) + '%' 
  WHERE 
    M.MonthNumber = MONTH(StartDate) 
    AND CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(X.ColumnName, CHARINDEX('_', X.ColumnName) + 1, 4)) = YEAR(StartDate) 
) 
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  _Results R
```